# How to click all links present on website using selenium in a loop?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

Steps :

1) Navigate to https://www.leicabiosystems.com/
2) Click on product tab
3) Hover on histology
4) Click on first link and again navigate back
5) repeat this for all links under histology

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I have tried doing it for one link under histology but i am not aware how we can do it using loop for all links present under histology

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below (note: this is just an example)

```
for (int i = 0; i < driver.findElements(locator).length; i++) {
    driver.findElements(locator)[i].click();
}
```